# how to built a new dataframe out of specific values of a variable of another dataframe

Tags: r, variables

Im a newbie to R and stuck with the following:

I've got a dataframe "neuedaten2" with many variables. One of them is named "specific_trips". Within that variable i've got 28 specific trips: 402, 4021, 4022, 508, 5081, 5082 and so forth. 
What i need is a new dataframe which just contains some of the specific trips and also keeps all the other variables. I've tried:

```
random_df_ev2 <- neuedaten2[neuedaten2$spcfct_ == "92404052",]
```

which works, but as soon as i add another specific trip like:

```
random_df_ev2 <- neuedaten2[neuedaten2$spcfct_ == "4022",] & neuedaten2[neuedaten2$spcfct_ == "508",]
```

it fails.

Hope that is a simple one..
Thanks for any advice.
Rickie

Comment: You need to combine the conditions when indexing: `neuedaten2[neuedaten2$spcfct_ == "4022" | neuedaten2$spcfct_ == "508", ]` or `neuedaten2[neuedaten2$spcfct_ %in% c("4022", "508"), ]` or `subset(neuedaten2, spcfct_ %in% c("4022", "508"))`.

Comment: Great, that worked! Thank you so much!!